# how to check syslog-ng daemon error status ?

Tags: syslog-ng

I need to check if the logs are successfully sent to the external server by syslog-ng. 
I am using UDP connection.

How do i check if any error occurred ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

UDP is fire and forget, so there is no direct way to check it. The mark-mode() option of syslog-ng could be used as a workaround: http://www.balabit.com/sites/default/files/documents/syslog-ng-ose-3.5-guides/en/syslog-ng-ose-v3.5-guide-admin/html-single/index.html#global-options-mark-mode as this way there are regular messages even in case of inactivity.